# Pass widget values within ui in Shiny

Tags: checkbox, shiny, widget, dropdown

In Shiny, how do you pass the value of a `selectInput` widget to another widget? This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
selectInput("dataset", "",
            choices = c("A", "B", "C"), # A to C are datasets in memory
            selected = "B")

conditionalPanel("input.tabs === 'tab'",
                 checkboxGroupInput("checkboxes", "",
                 names(?), # I want the column names of the selected dataset
                 selected = names(?))) # and here too
```

Specifically, I want the value of `selectInput`, presumably a reference to a dataset in memory, to be used by `checkboxGroupInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need dynamic parameters in the `ui`, you need to use `uiOutput` in conjunction with `renderUI`. [Read more](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/renderUI.html)

### ui.R

In the `ui` define the `uiOutput` that will be rendered in server side:

```
selectInput("dataset", "",
              choices = c("A", "B", "C"), # A to C are datasets in memory
              selected = "B"),
uiOutput("ui")
```

### server.R

In server side use `renderUI`:

```
output$ui <- renderUI( {
      conditionalPanel("input.tabs === 'tab'",
                       checkboxGroupInput("checkboxes", "",
                                          input$dataset,
                                          selected = input$dataset))
})
```

You can access the selected values with `input$dataset`. If you need the `choices`, you could store it in a vector first and supply it to both `selectInput`s

Comment: This is what I needed thank you! One last caveat if I may... when the user selects a checkbox, I want to filter a datable with `dataset[, input$checkboxes, drop = FALSE]` but `input$checkboxes` does not appear to recognize the checkboxes being selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not appear to recognize the checkboxes?" Can you share some code for that? Something like this should work with a `tableOutput`: `output$tbl <- renderTable( {
    req(input$checkboxes)
    dataset[, input$checkboxes, drop = FALSE]
  })`

Comment: In ui.R:

`tabsetPanel(id = "tabs", tabPanel("Data", style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height:600px", DT::dataTableOutput("data")))`

In server.R:

`output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, inherits = TRUE)
    DT::datatable(dataset[, input$checkboxes, drop = FALSE],
                  options = list(pageLength = 10),
                  filter = "top")
})`

Comment: I got it! I forgot to add `req(input$checkboxes)`. It works now!